# Relic - Activated Corruption Cards and discarding

Tags: relic

Quick question regarding corruption cards: If you have 5 corruption cards and one of them is activated because it has an activation value of 5, what happens if your discard one or several corruption cards later in the game? Is value 5 card activated forever until you discard it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  activated corruption cards remain activated until they are discarded via an event or action that instructs you to discard them.

Also,  note that you only check to activate corruption cards as you receive them.  eg.  if the first corruption card you recieve is a 5 it does not activate and is placed face down.  Even if you reach 5 corruption cards later in the game,  that first card will not activate.

You can find this information on page 17 of the rule book